# Java android, phone skipped migrations

Tags: java, android, android-room

I have a problems with migration in andorid room database. When a phone have an application in database verssion 31 and later do not update a application and now I update an application my application is crash and I have :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: A migration from 32 to 38 was required but not found. Please provide the necessary Migration path via RoomDatabase.Builder.addMigration(Migration ...) or allow for destructive migrations via one of the RoomDatabase.Builder.fallbackToDestructiveMigration* methods.
        at androidx.room.RoomOpenHelper.onUpgrade(RoomOpenHelper.java:98)
```

and this what I have :

```
private static DbManager buildDatabaseInstance(Context context) {
    return Room.databaseBuilder(context,
            DbManager.class,
            DB_NAME)
            .addMigrations(MIGRATION_31_32, MIGRATION_33_35, MIGRATION_35_36, MIGRATION_36_37,MIGRATION_37_38)
            .allowMainThreadQueries().build();
}

static final Migration MIGRATION_31_32 = new Migration(32, 33) {
    @Override
    public void migrate(SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE 'Orders' " + " ADD COLUMN 'lon' REAL");
        database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE 'Orders' " + " ADD COLUMN 'lat' REAL");
    }
};
static final Migration MIGRATION_33_35 = new Migration(33, 35) {
    @Override
    public void migrate(SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE 'Orders' " + " ADD COLUMN 'lats' REAL  not null DEFAULT  0");

    }
};

static final Migration MIGRATION_35_36 = new Migration(35, 36) {
    @Override
    public void migrate(SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE 'change_job_status' " + " ADD COLUMN 'login' text");

    }
};

static final Migration MIGRATION_36_37 = new Migration(36, 37) {
    @Override
    public void migrate(SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE 'Orders' " + " ADD COLUMN 'category_nr' INTEGER  not null DEFAULT  0");
    }
};
static final Migration MIGRATION_37_38 = new Migration(37, 38) {
    @Override
    public void migrate(SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE 'Orders' " + " ADD COLUMN 'status_date' text");
    }
};
```

What I should to do to do all migrations

Comment: Check your SQL: double quote is used to escape names. Single quote is used for string literals. example: `ALTER TABLE "Orders" ADD COLUMN "lon" REAL`

Comment: migration with name "MIGRATION_31_32" is actually migrating from 32 to 33??? and you have application with database version 31 crash with that exception?